# Subview content being mysteriously offset in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uicollectionview, uitextview, offset

I'm experiencing a weird behavior in Interface Builder.  I almost feel like it's a glitch, but I'm hoping that I'm just misunderstanding something, or that someone knows what weird AutoLayout behavior I'm experiencing, or something.  I'll try to describe it as best I can...

I've got a ViewController in Interface Builder, with nothing but a UITextView.  Nothing unusual about the TextView, I just dragged it in from the sidebar, and it's the first thing I added.  But here's the thing: the text is offset by about 50 points.  There's nothing in the Size Inspector that would explain it, the text is just spaced down.  BUT, if I click and drag it around, the text pops back up to the top.  Then I drop it in a new place, and the text is offset again.

Here's where it gets really weird: if I drag a UICollectionView into that same ViewController, it's fine (the default cell is right up in the top left corner), but as soon as I delete the TextView, the default cell gets moved 50 points down in the CollectionView!  Now I have a CollectionView with an offset cell, and if I drag a new TextView back on, it's fine, but deleting the CollectionView adds the offset back to the new TextView!  The location of the views is irrelevant (either at the time of adding or later), the older view will always be offset.

And, just for an extra dose of weird: whichever view is offset, if I click and drag it to move it around, the other view will be offset until I drop it in its new location.  Oh, and deleting the ViewController entirely and starting again does nothing.  The behavior remains.

What black magic is this?!  This is the 8th ViewController I've added to my Storyboard (12th if you include abstract ViewControllers like TabBarControllers etc), and none of them had this issue.  Why would this forced-offset exist, and how do I stop it?  Is this some weird permutation of AutoLayout or something?  Or does this sound like a genuine glitch, and I should post on a tech support forum?

**EDIT:** Just to be clear: the offset does appear when the app is run in the Simulator.  IB shows that the frame isn't changing, the content is being offset within the frame, but whatever it is, it DOES show up in the final app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turned out to be turning off "Adjust Scroll View Insets" on the ViewController.

Sort of a weird behavior for the ViewController to present like that, adjusting a single ScrollView without any regard for its position or size, but at least it was an easy fix.

[image]

Comment: This was bugging me for weeks! I had a problem with two collection views in the same view controller. In one of them the cell template was positioned correctly at the top left corner, on the other the cell was placed at mid-height. Unchecking "Adjust Scroll View Insets" did the trick. THANK YOU SO MUCH!